# What is wrong with my code trying to find longest substring of a string that is in alphabetical order?

Tags: python

I need help on a problem that I am doing in a course. The exact details are below:

Assume **s is a string of lower case characters.**

Write a program that prints the **longest substring of s** in which the letters occur in **alphabetical order.**

For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl', then your program should print

*"Longest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh"*

In the case of ties, print the first substring. For example, if s = 'abcbcd', then your program should print

*"Longest substring in alphabetical order is: abc"*

I have written some code that achieves some correct answers but not all and I am unsure why.

This is my code

```
s = 'vettmlxvn'

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
substring = ""
highest_len = 0
highest_string = ""
counter = 0


for letter in s:
    counter += 1
    if s.index(letter) == 0:
        substring = substring + letter
        highest_len = len(substring)
        highest_string = substring
    else:
        x = alphabet.index(substring[-1])
        y = alphabet.index(letter)
        if y >= x:
            substring = substring + letter
            if counter == len(s) and len(substring) > highest_len:
                highest_len = len(substring)
                highest_string = substring
        else:
            if len(substring) > highest_len:
                highest_len = len(substring)
                highest_string = substring
                substring = "" + letter
            else:
                substring = "" + letter

print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + highest_string)
```

When I test for this specific string it gives me "lxv" instead of the correct answer: "ett". I do not know why this is and have even tried drawing a trace table so I can trace variables and I should be getting "ett".
Maybe I have missed something simple but can someone explain why it is not working.

I know there are probably easier ways to do this problem but I am a beginner in python and have been working on this problem for a long time.

Just want to know what is wrong with my code.

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is probably relying on `index`, it will return the index of the *first* match it finds.

Comment: however `index` has a second argument that's the index to start searching from (third argument is for where to end but you don't need to use that)

Comment: I'm not sure about your approach based on index.  Would you want a simpler more robust approach?

Comment: There is no need for an `alphabet` string you can compare two characters. No need to rely on `index`. Would you like me to give you a simpler approach?

Comment: Yes please, I do not know how to compare two characters

Comment: @dav123_34 I did give you an alternate approach and figured  out whats wrong with your code. See my Answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved your Problem with an alternate simpler approach.

You can compare 2 characters like numbers. `a` comes before `b` in the alphabet, that means the expression `'a' < 'b'` is `True`

```py
def longest_substring(s):
    # Initialize the longest substring
    longest = ""
    # Initialize the current substring
    current = ""
    # Loop through the string
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i == 0:
            # If it's the first letter, add it to the current substring
            current += s[i]
        else:
            if s[i] >= s[i-1]:
                # If the current letter is greater than or equal to the previous letter,
                # add it to the current substring
                current += s[i]
            else:
                # If the current letter is less than the previous letter,
                # check if the current substring is longer than the longest substring
                # and update the longest substring if it is
                if len(current) > len(longest):
                    longest = current
                current = s[i]
    # Once the loop is done,
    # check again if the current substring is longer than the longest substring
    if len(current) > len(longest):
        longest = current
    return longest

print(longest_substring("azcbobobegghakl"))
print(longest_substring("abcbcd"))
print(longest_substring("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
print(longest_substring("vettmlxvn"))
```

Output:

```
beggh
abc
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ett
```

I haven't figured out what's wrong with your code yet. I will update this if I figured it out.

## Edit

---

So commented some stuff out and changed one thing.

Here's the working code:

```py
s = 'vettmlxvn'

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
substring = ""
highest_len = 0
highest_string = ""
counter = 0

for letter in s:
    counter += 1
    if s.index(letter) == 0:
        substring = substring + letter
        # highest_len = len(substring)
        # highest_string = substring
    else:
        x = alphabet.index(substring[-1])
        y = alphabet.index(letter)
        if y >= x:
            substring = substring + letter
            if counter == len(s) and len(substring) > highest_len:
                highest_len = len(substring)
                highest_string = substring
        else:
            if len(substring) > len(highest_string): # changed highest_len to len(highest_string)
                #highest_len = len(substring)
                highest_string = substring
                substring = "" + letter
            else:
                substring = "" + letter

print("Longest substring in alphabetical order is: " + highest_string)
```

You are overwriting `highest_string` at the wrong time. Only overwrite it if the substrings ends and after checking if it's greater than the longest found before.

Outputs:

```
Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ett
```

Comment: Thank you, I  forgot I could just use comparison operators on characters

Comment: @dav123_34 I solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate Approach**

- Break input string into substrings

  - Where each substring is increasing
- Find the longest substring

**Code**

```
def longest_increasing_substring(s):
    # Break s into substrings which are increasing
    incr_subs = []
    for c in s:
        if not incr_subs or incr_subs[-1][-1] > c:# check alphabetical order of last letter of current
                                                  # string to current letter
            incr_subs.append('')                  # Start new last substring since not in order
        incr_subs[-1] += c                        # append to last substsring

    return max(incr_subs, key = len)              # substring with max length
```

**Test**

```
for s in ['vettmlxvn', 'azcbobobegghakl', 'abcbcd']:
    print(f'{s} -> {longest_increasing_substring(s)}')
```

**Output**

```
vettmlxvn -> ett
azcbobobegghakl -> beggh
abcbcd -> abc
```

Comment: Thanks, never thought of it like that

Comment: @dav123_34 -- Glad to help.  Grouping into subgroups comes up often so it's a good technique to remember.